# python logging. custom fields

Tags: python, logging

I have a simple Flask application running. I need the log messages as json. That works fine.

But how can I customize the values of the logging?

threadName -> thread_name

levelname -> level_name

etc...

```
import time
import datetime
import connexion
import logmatic
import logging
import pytz

app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./')
app.add_api('swagger.json')

logger = logging.getLogger()

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(logmatic.JsonFormatter(fmt="%(threadName)s %(message)s %(levelname)s %(levelno)s) %(name)s"))

logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Actual log output:

```
{"threadName": "MainThread", "message": " * Debugger PIN: 188-641-578", "levelname": "INFO", "levelno": 20, "name": "werkzeug", "timestamp": "2018-06-26T11:38:21.780630Z"}
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem a bit more? I'm not really sure what you're asking for.

Comment: I need the values with an underscore..thread_name (not threadName)